# Powershell pipe in string

Tags: powershell

I was trying to rename some files with the powershell script below

```
 powershell.exe "& { Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -Replace '.txt','.csv' } }"
```

But the `$_.name` seems to be parsed when the `"& command"` is executed, so it complains that it does not know `.name` (with the `$_` already removed). Executing it without the outer string resolves the problem, but for other reasons is not feasible in my case.

How to escape the `$_.name`?

Comment: Are you running this from PowerShell? If so, you don't need the `powershell "& {...}"` wrapper. Just run the command directly. Otherwise the `$_` shouldn't be expanded.

Comment: Try using single quotes on the outer string and double quotes inside?

Comment: How are you running this command? With PSv5 it works as expected when I execute it from CMD...

Comment: I always thought that parameters of type expression should be encased in round brackets. `powershell.exe "& { Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName ( $_.name -Replace '.txt','.csv' ) }"`

Comment: @JamesC. It even worked for me from cmd.exe on a 2008R2 with Powershell 2.0. (Sadly I wasn't right about round brackets)

Comment: @Vesper In that context curly brackets are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works perfectly fine:

```
powershell.exe "& { Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { `$_.name -Replace '.txt','.csv' } }"
```

Comment: For me this errors with "Rename-Item : The input to the script block for parameter 'NewName' failed. The term '$_.name' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Comment: If you want screenshot i can post it

Comment: It works only when run from within PowerShell, in which case you don't need the `powershell.exe "&{...}"` at all. It throws an error when run from outside PowerShell (a Command Prompt for instance) where you would actually need the construct.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with your original command, but personally I would use the [`Path.ChangeExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.changeextension%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead of `-replace`:

```
powershell.exe -command "& {Get-ChildItem *.txt | Rename-Item -NewName { [io.path]::ChangeExtension($_.name, 'csv') }}"
```

Or as you seem to be calling PowerShell from the command line, you could just use the 'rename' command instead (and not use PowerShell at all):

```
ren *.txt *.csv
```

Answer (score -2):

```
powershell.exe "& {
    Get-ChildItem -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object {`$_.Name}
}"
```

Backticks  escape special characters in PowerShell strings

```
`
```

Comment: You've excluded the `Rename-Item` command, which is a key part of the OPs code.

Comment: @JamesC. I chose to post some code that is _less damaging_ for the uninitiated to run.